# Go for gymming, come for... ( or go/come)

Tags: word-usage

Is "for" required here?

> There's a gym there and people go for gymming there.
>
> There's a gym there and people go for working out there.

Will "for" be used or dropped?

And if I use "come"?

> People come for gymming here.
>
> People come for working out here.

Can "from" be dropped in the sentences above?

Comment: I think in the second case you meant to ask if "for" can also be dropped, right?

Comment: "Gymming" is _not a word_.

Answer (score 2):

*gym* is not normally used as a verb, so don't use *gymming*. Even if it were a verb, it would be redundant if you already mentioned the noun *gym* in the same sentence. I also agree with @Bee's comment. *for* is not the preposition I would use; *to* is better. Here's how I would phrase the first example:

> People go to the gym there to work out.

And the second:

> People come here to work out.